# Using IronPython on Mono in PyCharm IDE

Tags: ubuntu, mono, pycharm, ironpython

please help how to setup Pycharm IDE in order to use IronPython on Mono.

To run the python script from terminal is easy:
`mono ipy.exe script.py`.
but how make Pycharm recognize it as an interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer by myself.
Added a Local interpreter to ipy.exe (there were na error that Pycharm can't configure SDK)
I setup an alias for mono ipy:
`bash
azh@azh:~$ alias ipy="mono /home/azh/Downloads/pythonnet-master/IronLanguages/bin/Release/ipy.exe"`

After that I added a custom script in Pycharm:
`mono /%YOURPATHTOIRONPYTHON/IronPython-2.7.6rc2/ipy.exe`
[Run -- Edit Configurations -- Defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kogvG.png)